# EmberJs - how/where does the addon.scss file in an add-on gets mapped into the consuming app

Tags: javascript, ember.js, import, zurb-foundation

I have a custom made add-on in a directory outside of the host application's directory. Then, importing the add-on via the package.json file by providing the relative path under the ember-addons object, in

```
paths : [ '<relative path>']
```

I have provided the styles for the components in the add-on under addon/styles/addon.scss. I am using foundation for the styles in the components, so my addon.scss has some @import and the imported files have @import statements which are sourced from bower_component/foundation/*

This setup works fine while serving the dummy app in the add-on. But fails to successfully build the consuming app with the add-on included. Failing at the @import statements of the foundation styles in the app.. although bower_components in the consuming app has the foundation module with respective files in place.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the file into your app.scss file? e.g.

```
@import "../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

If you import it there it will compile and include when you are doing a build.

Pete